# catch-all and redirect to home instead of 404 error with Nuxt JS

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, nuxt.js, vue-router

With VueJS and Vue-Router I can add something like this to redirect to home component instead of 404 error page:

```
routes: {
    {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/home',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirect: '/home',
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        ...
    },
}
```

It is possible to catch inexisting url's and redirect to home with Nuxt JS?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea but i'm not sure that is it the best way or not

in your `layout/error.vue` file make a `beforeMount` function like this:

```
beforeMount() {
    if (this.error.statusCode === 404) {
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  },
```